# Differences in quantile function

Tags: r

I am struggling with some strange behaviour in R, with the quantile function.

I have two sets of numeric data, and a custom boxplot stats function (which someone helped me write, so I am actually not too sure about every detail):

```
sample_lang = c(91, 122,  65,  90,  90, 102,
            98,  94,  84,  86, 108, 104,
            94, 110, 100,  86,  92,  92,
            124, 108,  82,  65, 102,  90, 114,
            88,  68, 112,  96,  84,  92,
            80, 104, 114, 112, 108,  68,
            92,  68,  63, 112, 116)

sample_vocab = c(96, 136,  81,  92,  95,
                 112, 101,  95,  97,  94,
                 117,  95, 111, 115,  88,
                 92, 108,  81, 130, 106,  
                 91,  95, 119, 103, 132, 103,
                 65, 114, 107, 108,  86, 
                 100,  98, 111, 123, 123, 117,
                 82, 100,  97,  89, 132, 114)

my.boxplot.stats <- function (x, coef = 1.5, do.conf = TRUE, do.out = TRUE) {
  if (coef < 0) 
    stop("'coef' must not be negative")
  nna <- !is.na(x)
  n <- sum(nna)
  #stats <- stats::fivenum(x, na.rm = TRUE)
  stats <- quantile(x, probs = c(0.15, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.85), na.rm = TRUE)
  iqr <- diff(stats[c(2, 4)])
  if (coef == 0) 
    do.out <- FALSE
  else {
    out <- if (!is.na(iqr)) {
      x < (stats[2L] - coef * iqr) | x > (stats[4L] + coef * 
                                            iqr)
    }
    else !is.finite(x)
    if (any(out[nna], na.rm = TRUE)) 
      stats[c(1, 5)] <- range(x[!out], na.rm = TRUE)
  }
  conf <- if (do.conf) 
    stats[3L] + c(-1.58, 1.58) * iqr/sqrt(n)
  list(stats = stats, n = n, conf = conf, out = if (do.out) x[out & 
                                                                nna] else numeric())
}
```

However, when I call `quantile` and `my.boxplot.stats` on the same set of data, I am getting different quantile results for the `sample_vocab` data (but it appears consistent with the `sample_lang` data), and I am not sure why:

```
> quantile(sample_vocab, probs = c(0.15, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.85), na.rm=TRUE)
  15%   25%   50%   75%   85% 
 89.6  94.5 101.0 114.0 118.4 
> 
> my.boxplot.stats(sample_vocab)
$stats
  15%   25%   50%   75%   85% 
 81.0  94.5 101.0 114.0 136.0
```

Could someone help me understand what is happening? Please note, I am reasonably experienced with programming, but have no formal training in R, I am learning on my own.

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Well, quantile does what the documentation says. Your function calls quantile, but then apparently `if (any(out[nna], na.rm = TRUE))` gets triggered and so the next line `stats[c(1, 5)] <- range(x[!out], na.rm = TRUE)` modifies the first and last values of `stats`, which are the values where you see differences. That's what is happening. What the boxplot stats code is correct or not (or what it's trying to do) isn't very clear.

Comment: @Gregor - thanks, I think you are right. Do you know what: if (any(out[nna], na.rm = TRUE)) is actually doing? It seems like my sample_vocab is triggering this, but sample_lang is not? I am having trouble understanding the syntax..

Answer (score 1):

The relevant bit of code is right here:

```
  if (coef == 0) 
    do.out <- FALSE
  else {
    out <- if (!is.na(iqr)) {
      x < (stats[2L] - coef * iqr) | x > (stats[4L] + coef * 
                                            iqr)
    }
    else !is.finite(x)
    if (any(out[nna], na.rm = TRUE)) 
      stats[c(1, 5)] <- range(x[!out], na.rm = TRUE)
  }
```

Basically, if `coef != 0` (in your case `coef` is 1.5, the default function parameter), then the first and last elements of the reported quantiles are replaced with the minimum and maximum data value within `coef * iqr` of the 25% and 75% quantiles, where `iqr` is the distance between those quantiles.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But then why is the reported 85% for sample_lang not 124? If I am understanding correctly, the iqr is 22, so 108+1.5*22 = 130...

Comment: I reviewed, further where I got the help from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29070763/how-to-create-a-boxplot-in-r-with-box-representing-the-15th-and-85th-percentile - the majority of the code is in fact unchanged from the original boxplot.stats function, so perhaps there is a rule for when the 1st and 5th values are changed to the ones you precisely mentioned..

Comment: The condition: if (any(out[nna], na.rm = TRUE)), seems to be changing those values. I am not sure exactly what this condition means, but seems like sample_lang does not meet the condition, but sample_vocab does.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. The sample data, I provided above is an example as I mentioned. The sample_lang quantiles are not changed, but sample_vocab is. Noting my first comment to your answer, I don't understand why the quantiles for sample_lang are not changed, if what you are saying is true.